# How can I write to JSON without overwriting the entire file, but instead update a part?

Tags: javascript, json, merge, discord.js

I am making a discord economy bot in javascript.
I have a JSON which saves every user's data.
The system used is:

- Save the json in object form to a variable
- modify the object
- Overwrite the json with the new data

It works fine, but if 2 users have the file open and both of them edit their copy of the json and then overwrite the json, the second user will overwrite the first user's data.
I thought about using a DB but it's too much work to change everything so i wanted to just do something that only modifies the part of the right user, how can i do that?

Comment: You need to a) do all three steps each time something changes b) put changes in a queue so users are unable to accidentally change something at the same time

Comment: You need mutual exclusion. There are various algorithms to deal with the reader/writer but the simplest solution would be a queue to line up the changes

Comment: you can find diff/merge tools for the object so that both user's changes get applied if not in conflict. you'll need to keep a copy of the object live in ram, and serialize that whole thing to a file every time the data changes.

Comment: @CptPiepmatz you definitely do not need to be aware of who is interacting with the file. Absolutely overkill to keep track of concurrent uses which no doubt will result in OP deadlocking something

Comment: I thought of an even simpler solution. In the function that gets the json and converts to js object, I pass user id too, and then when I update the json I pass in the save function user id and data, so only the part of the user gets changed. What do you think?